# How can I resolve glib.h not found clang compiler on Mac with VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, homebrew, glib

I'm experimenting with using `VSCode` for `C` development on Mac. I've been having trouble getting `VSCode` to find `glib.h`. I installed `glib` with `brew`.

I've been using `pkg-config` to identify my path:

```
> pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include
```

And, have set my `includePath` accordingly:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include"
            ],
```

`brew ls glib`:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gdbus
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gdbus-codegen
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gio
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gio-querymodules
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/glib-compile-resources
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/glib-compile-schemas
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/glib-genmarshal
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/glib-gettextize
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/glib-mkenums
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gobject-query
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gresource
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gsettings
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gtester
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/bin/gtester-report
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/etc/bash_completion.d/ (5 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/gio-unix-2.0/ (9 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0/ (262 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/pkgconfig/ (8 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/ (10 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/aclocal/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/bash-completion/ (5 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/gdb/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/gettext/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/glib-2.0/ (13 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/share/locale/ (98 files)
```

But, building from within VSCode results in:

```
fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
```

Comment: Do you have the glib-devel package for your distro installed? Some distros break the libraries up into the shared object library needed by other applications and the development version that contains the headers, etc.. for your own development with it. Don't know how Mac does it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I added the output of `brew ls glib` above. I don't see a separate `glib-devel` package installed. Maybe I should use MacPorts.

Comment: No guarantee Mac splits the package into a glib and glib-devel. Some Linux distros do, some don't. I don't have a Mac, so I don't know how they do it, but it was worth checking. Check which (or neither) or `"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0"` and `"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/glib-2.0/include"` exist and whether they contain `glib.h`. `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/lib/glib-2.0/include/glib.h` and the same for the other will do. Then I'd do `find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib -type f -name glib.h` to recursively search all of the glib directory for the header.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, it exists at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0/glib.h`. I've even been able to make Intellisense to work before with a different include path. But, then it says I'm missing some other glib header (different headers depending on the include path).

Comment: That matches your `"includePath"` entry of `"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0"` exactly, so that doesn't make a lot of sense. In your code you have `#include <glib.h>` and not `glib-2.0/glib.h` right? Try compiling from a terminal in a directory containing  your code directly (with `gcc` I presume) add `\`pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags --libs\`` as an option and see what gcc says.